# p2p RTMFP controlling movieClip frame action

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, p2p, rtmfp, netconnection

I'm trying to control a movieClip using p2p netconnection.  I understand that I can control properties of a movieClip --- such as

```
case "NetGroup.SendTo.Notify":
rover.x = event.info.message.x;
rover.y = event.info.message.y;
myFencer.fence.visible = event.info.message.visible;
```

Can I also control a frame Action ? the following doen't work ---

```
case "NetGroup.SendTo.Notify":
score.FrameEvent = event.info.message.FrameEvent;

obj.Event = score.gotoAndStop("green");
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will work.**

I suspect your "green" label.Recheck it again.

This works

```
_root.gotoAndStop(_currentframe+1);
```

Comment: I can't get it.  Basically I'm trying to send a message to the second swf. I'm able to send properties like visibilty and .x .y position.  But I can't send a frame action ?  see the following                                                case "NetGroup.SendTo.Notify":
             rover.x = event.info.message.x;
             rover.y = event.info.message.y;
    myFencer.fence.visible = event.info.message.visible;
    score.frameEvent = event.info.message.frameEvent;

Comment: `obj.frameEvent = score.gotoAndStop("green");`

Comment: @bobsmo, The second swf what you mean is the `same swf` right ?. What was the trace value of `event.info.message.FrameEvent` ?

Comment: (yes - the same swfs) i can't get a trace to display any event.  here is what i have - On a button click send a message to the swf `    case "NetGroup.SendTo.Notify":
             rover.x = event.info.message.x;
             rover.y = event.info.message.y;
    myFencer.fence.visible = event.info.message.visible;
    score.frameEvent = event.info.message.frameEvent;
    ttrace.text = event.info.message.frameEvent.toString();
             break;`

Comment: the trace doesn't display anything `function myClickredStart (e:MouseEvent):void{
  obj.frameEvent = score.gotoAndStop("green");
  score.gotoAndStop("red");
  trace(score);
  trace(obj.frameEvent);
  greenStart.visible=false;
  redStart.visible=false;
}`